# How can I organize this python structure?

Tags: python, numpy

```
[{'id': '1_2003_01_01', 'longitude': -56.6107063111071, 'latitude': -14.196840002932301, 'time': 1041379200000, 'NDVI': 0.7633000000000001}, {'id': '1_2003_01_17', 'longitude': -56.6107063111071, 'latitude': -14.196840002932301, 'time': 1042761600000, 'NDVI': 0.14020000000000002}, ...
```

I want to sort by 'time', and derive a numpy array of NDVI and another one of EVI, and also the date vector.

Is it possible?

Comment: yep, it´s a list of dict. Each element is a dict. But for some reason there´s a "1_" before the date.

Comment: yes it is. Have you another question ?

Comment: I'd assign that list to some variable `L`, then make a dataframe using it. i.e. `data = pd.DataFrame(L)`. Then you can do all sort of things.

Comment: how can I do it? converting to pandas dataframe is better?

Comment: what exactly is EVI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do as in comments and just push it into pandas DataFrame constructor:

```
import np as numpy
impoty pd as pandas

ld = [{'id': '1_2003_01_01', 'longitude': -56.6107063111071, 'latitude': -14.196840002932301, 'time': 1041379200000, 'NDVI': 0.7633000000000001}, {'id': '1_2003_01_17', 'longitude': -56.6107063111071, 'latitude': -14.196840002932301, 'time': 1042761600000, 'NDVI': 0.14020000000000002}]
df = pd.DataFrame(ld).sort_values('time')
```

and df yields:

```
    id              longitude   latitude    time            NDVI
0   1_2003_01_01    -56.610706  -14.19684   1041379200000   0.7633
1   1_2003_01_17    -56.610706  -14.19684   1042761600000   0.1402
```

u can then call `df['NDVI']` and get series or numpy array if u do `df['NDVI'].values`.